# Shopping cart price rules , ignore conditions?

Tags: cart, price, rules, shopping

I have Magento 1.8.1 
I am really desperate with this issue i try to set a shopping cart rule but , when i put a condition , only for SKU: XXX or only when total of cart is XX , it ignore the condition and make the discount for all orders and all products.. someone can help me?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Jennifier,it may you shopping cart setting issue:

goto `admin>select you shipping cart rul`e and then goto `Action tab`

and check here

**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)** and  you can `set  conditions for one product shopping cart rules`.

Ex:
Backend:
[image]

Frontend Result:

[image]